# Массив. Сортировка

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Нужно создать класс со статическим методом, для сортировки массива. Например по маршруту. Совсем запутался, помогите советом.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bus[] B = new Bus[10];
        B[0] = new Bus("Иванов И.И.", 9535, 921, "МАЗ 103", 2001, 750000);
        B[1] = new Bus("Баранов Б.Б.", 2221, 15, "МАЗ 105", 2009, 450000);
        B[2] = new Bus("Волков В.В.", 3561, 37, "МАЗ 104", 2002, 600000);
        B[3] = new Bus("Грибоедов Г.Г.", 4551, 56, "МАЗ 203", 2015, 250000);
        B[4] = new Bus("Данилов Д.Д.", 5531, 921, "МАЗ 103", 2007, 500000);
        B[5] = new Bus("Емелин Е.Е.", 7242, 9, "МАЗ 105", 2002, 750000);
        B[6] = new Bus("Зиновьев З.З.", 8965, 61, "МАЗ 105", 2003, 707000);
        B[7] = new Bus("Жеглов Г.Г.", 1253, 9, "МАЗ 203", 2015, 251000);
        B[8] = new Bus("Иванов Б.И.", 1254, 15, "МАЗ 105", 2001, 752000);
        B[9] = new Bus("Шарапов В.И.", 5561, 37, "МАЗ 203", 2015, 252000);
    }
}
```

```java
class Bus {
    public String Driver; // Фамилия и инициалы водителя
    public int Number;    // Номер автобуса
    public int route;     // Номер маршрута
    public String model;  // марка
    public int year;      // год
    public int run;       // пробег
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(B, Comparator.comparing(Bus::getRoute));
```

Comment: Или реализовать Comparator для Bus и вызвать просто Arrays.sort(B);

Answer (score 0):

Можно цепочку компараторов указать - по каким полям, в каком порядке и в каком направлении сравнивать. В классе `Bus` должны присутствовать геттеры для соответствующих полей.

```java
Arrays.sort(B, Comparator
        .comparing(Bus::getDriver, Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Bus::getNumber, Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Bus::getRoute));
```

---

См. [`Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator))